# Wagtail - running tests raises psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "draft_title" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to run my app tests (Django v1.11 and Wagtail v2.2.1) but I'm getting an exception while the test is creating the test databases:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fleon/.virtualenvs/virmyasb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "draft_title" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 0001, 1, 1, Root, root, t, f, /, , f, , null, null, f, 1, null, f, null, null, null, null, null).`

When looking at the full stack trace, there's an error inside a Wagtail file:

`[...]
lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/core/migrations/0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field.py", line 30, in initial_data
[...]`

The Python code in such line is:

```
# Create root page
root = Page.objects.create(
    title="Root",
    slug='root',
    content_type=page_content_type,
    path='0001',
    depth=1,
    numchild=1,
    url_path='/',
)
```

which is not setting the draft_title, hence violating the not-null constraint.

Please note I'm using two different databases (base.py):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(),
    'thedbname': {
        'NAME': 'thedbname',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'thedbuser',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'myhost',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
    }
}
```

and the tests work if I remove the MySQL database (?)

Comment: Can you share the migration file (`0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field`)? It looks like you enter NULLs into non-NULL columns.

Answer (score 1):

The `Page.draft_title` field was added to Wagtail in the migration `wagtail/core/migrations/0040_page_draft_title.py`. Since migrations always work on a frozen version of the model as it existed at the time of the migration, the code in `0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field.py` is valid - `draft_title` did not exist at that point.

The error suggests that migrations have happened out of the normal order for some reason - I'd suggest checking the migrations in your project for any dependency lines such as `run_before` that might affect the order - or are being re-run on a database that already has migrations applied (but doesn't have them logged in the `django_migrations` table, so Django isn't aware of this).

Comment: Please take into account I only have this issue if I enable both PostgreSQL and MySQL databases: as soon as I commented the MySQL database out, my tests just run fine (?). As a "postmortem", when the test crashes it leaves the test databases behind, and the MySQL one misses a lot of model tables and/or table structures: for example, the wagtailcore_page misses the draft_title field, and no Page subclass models are created (no home_* tables).

Comment: Also, it has been just today that I have upgraded from Wagtail v2.1.1 to v.2.2.1 so the draft_title field creation migration has just been executed today.